# Probability of complements with intersection.

Tags: probability

I have this problem: to express the probability of $$P(A\cap\overline B\cap\overline C)\;,\;\;\text{and of}\;\;\;P(\overline A\cap\overline B\cap\overline C)$$

when we know $\;P(A), P(B), P(C)\;$ and probability of intersections of any two of them. It is also given that $\;A\cup B\cup C=\Omega=\;$ all the space of the probabilities.

This is what I can do until now: I think $\;P(\overline A\cap\overline B\cap\overline C)=0\;$ , because if there is something in $\;\overline A\cap\overline B\cap\overline C\;$ then it can't be in $\;\Omega\;$, because $\;A\cup B\cup C=\Omega\;$ and then everything must be in at least one of $\;A,B,C\;$ . I think my solution is not strong as it looks like set theory only and I can't make it more like probability.

For the second one I am lost, but I think it could be helpful if we write $\;A\cap\overline B\cap\overline C=A\cap\neg\left(B\cap C\right)\;$ , but again I go towards the set theory too much, I feel .

Something else: I think we can assume $\;|\Omega|<\infty\;$ because we are in the beginning of this and we haven't seen sigma algebras (I don't know this but it looks like it is going to be in the end of semester, maybe).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can use $P(\bar A \cap \bar B \cap \bar C) + P(A \cap \bar B \cap \bar C) = P(\bar B \cap \bar C)$

Comment: *"I think my solution is not strong as it looks like set theory only."*  Personally I find it perfectly fine, but if you'd like to use more probability words, then you can use "Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion" to say $P(E) = 1-P(\overline{E})$ on the event $\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}\cap \overline{C}$ and use De Morgan's laws to simplify into $\Omega$, and using $P(\Omega)=1$.  I don't see how the size of $\Omega$ affects the proof at all.  By assumption, $A\cup B\cup C=\Omega$ so it is $\sigma$-finite, so there shouldn't be anything weird happening.

Comment: Thank you very much @Siméon

Comment: Thank you very much @JMoravitz

Comment: @Siméon Am I right when I write  $\;P(\overline B\cap\overline C)=P(\overline{B\cup C})\;$ . I'm still not very sure with de Morgan laws. Thanks.

Comment: @AntoineNemesioParras Yes, that is correct, however it is more common to see overbars above operation symbols only if enclosed in parenthesis.  I.e., I normally see it as $P\left(\overline{(B\cup C)}\right)$.  Personally, I am in the habit of using $~^c$ to denote complement, however the textbook I am teaching from uses $'$ to denote complement.  I suppose it depends what book you studied from which you use.  All three are common enough to see.  As for the mathematics involved, yes $\overline{(B\cap C)} = \overline{B}\cup\overline{C}$ and $\overline{(B\cup C)} = \overline{B}\cap\overline{C}$